# PHPExcel - cell formating

Tags: phpexcel

if I fill a cell with the value "0.07" and then define it as a percentage, excel turns this value into "7,00". Can someone tell me how to work correctly? thanks

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowCount,'0.07');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$rowCount)->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray(array('code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00));
```

if i change and set the value to "0,07" - excel means that the value is formatted as text.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found a simple solution:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowCount, 0.07/100);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$rowCount)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00%');
```

i am happy if it helps others.